# Go to a specific raw_input()?

Tags: python, python-2.7

So I'm trying to figure out how I can make this simple little program to go back to the raw_input if the user inputs something else then "yes" or "no".

```
a = raw_input("test: ")
while True:
    if a == "yes":
        print("yeyeye")
        break
    elif a == "no":
        print("nonono")
        break
    else:
        print("yes or no idiot")
```

This is what I got so far, I'm new and it's hard to understand. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Put the `raw_input` inside your while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @DavidG mentioned, just add your raw_input statement in loop:

```
while True:
    a = raw_input("Enter: ")
    if a == "yes":
        print("You have entered Yes")
        break
    elif a == "no":
        print("You have entered No")
        break
    else:
        print("yes or no idiot")
```

Answer (score 1):

Describe a condition checker for while and read input everytime when your condition is not meet. Inline returns are good for low quantity conditions but when your choice count is too much or condition in condition situations appear, inline returns are becoming trouble.

Thats why you must use condition checkers(like cloop) instead of inline returns.

```
cloop=True
while cloop:
    a = raw_input("test: ")
    if a == "yes":
        print("yeyeye")
        cloop=False
    elif a == "no":
        print("nonono")
        cloop=False
    else:
        print("yes or no idiot")
        cloop=True
```

Comment: Your answer has been flagged for 'low quality'. If you want to retain it then I would suggest that you edit it, adding an explanation about why it answers the question.

Comment: @BillBell is it ok for you?

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can put the first instruction inside the loop; in this way, every time the user inserts a value different to *yes* or *no* you can print a message and wait to a new input.

```
while True:
    a = raw_input("test: ")
    if a == "yes":
        print("yeyeye")
        break
    elif a == "no":
        print("nonono")
        break
   else:
        print("yes or no idiot")
```